# PDO show columns multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to execute two almost identical queries. But for some reason it keeps loading if I execute them both.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "show columns from auto_new";
$stmtColumns = $db->prepare($query);
$stmtColumns->execute();
$result = $stmtColumns->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($result as $r) {
    $velden .= $r["0"]. "| ";
}

$query = "show columns from auto_coc";
$stmtColumnsCoc = $db->prepare($query);
$stmtColumnsCoc->execute();
$resultCoc = $stmtColumnsCoc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($resultCoc as $r) {
    $velden .= $r["0"]. "| ";
}
```

If I only execute one of two queries it works just fine, but both doesn't work at all.

Also tried the following with no luck:
$auto_new = 'auto_new';
    $auto_coc = 'auto_coc';

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE TABLE_NAME =:auto_new OR TABLE_NAME = :auto_coc";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':auto_new', $auto_new, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':auto_coc', $auto_coc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

In both ways it keeps loading forever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to execute the commands via shell or phpmyadmin - did it work?

Comment: Yes, they work fine

Comment: How long does it loading? Did you check error log after loading?

Comment: It gives a 504 gateway error

Comment: Try to set these options: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: It doesn't show any errors, because I'm getting an 504 gateway timeout